# Validating absence of an element

Tags: java, selenium

I have  a test case:

```
Assert.assertTrue(test .verifyNoDrillDisplayForCourses());
```

and a `boolean` method **verifyNoDrillDisplayForCourses** which verifies      `element("xyz")` is not displayed,

```
    try{
         if(element("xyz"). isDisplayed())
         return false;

     else return true;
     }
     catch (Exception e) 
     {

        return false;
     }
   }
```

But the assertion fails as `java .lang .AssertionError:expected [true]` but found `[false]`. I am unable to figure out why?

Comment: You need to post more code to get answer

Comment: This is the code, i just need to verify that element is not displayed but i am confused with what return  statement to add in order to make assertion true.

Comment: make is false if screen is not displaying then your assert will true

Answer (score 2):

The `isDisplayed()` method will throw an `StaleElementReferenceException`, if the given element is not in the DOM anymore. So you have to change the catch statement to `return true;`.

Comment: Still my assertion fails

Comment: if the assertion fails that it means your element is visible isn't it?

Comment: My element is not visible and that is the problem.

Comment: Can you share the url of the page what you are testing?

Comment: My assertion passed.Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

If you're testing for the presence of an element, if it's not found an exception will be thrown. So if you find it you're returning false, if you can't find it you're also returning false.

When testing for **non-presence** of an element you should have the catch block return **true**!

```
    try{
       if(element("xyz").isDisplayed()) {
             return false;
       } else return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {

    return false;
    }
    }
```

I believe your if statement is missing correct formatting from what you copied over.

I've amended it above, but in case try it like this:

```
if(element("xyz").isDisplayed()) {
         return false;
   } else return true;
```

Comment: Apart from return true in catch are there any changes in my method that i need to make .

Comment: Not that I can tell of the top of my head. You can change the exception type to element not found, but aside from that your code seems fine.

Comment: I tried return true but still my assertion is failing .

Comment: So is your code actually throwing an exception?
Would you be able to add in stack trace?

Comment: No my assertion is failing.

Comment: Try looking at your if statement, it looks dodgy. Otherwise all I can suggest is maybe to try a different method to .isDisplayed()

Are you waiting for the page to load before calling this method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83721/discussion-between-rkstr22-and-iridann).

Comment: Could you please mark whichever answer helped you solve your issue and close the question? Regards

Answer (score 0):

Following code helped:

```
 public boolean verifyNoelement()

 {

 try


{
           if(element("element").isDisplayed())
           {
           return false;
           }
           return false;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             logMessage("No element displayed");
            return true;
        }


    }
```